# How to make swagger 2.0 support WebApi area?

Tags: asp.net, swagger, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I am integreted swagger-ui(version 2.0) into my Asp.Net WebApi 4.0 project.This is my route config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Common_Get",
                routeTemplate: "common/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Get" },
                constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
            );


 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Active_Get",
                routeTemplate: "active/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Get" },
                constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
            );
```

And the swagger-ui generate document contains dulplicate items.`common` and `active` has the same controller+action.Like this:

```
get /common/Advert/GetAdvertise/{id} 
get /active/Advert/GetAdvertise/{id}

get /common/award/GetAward/{id} 
get /active/award/GetAward/{id}
```

How to avoid this problem or enable swagger support area(whatever the name).I could specify each controller's area. The correct result may like this:

```
get /common/Advert/GetAdvertise/{id}
get /active/Award/GetAward/{id}
```

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle ?

Comment: Yes,I am using Swashbuckle.